# How can I study the properties of outliers in high-dimensional data?

Tags: data-visualization, cluster-analysis, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have a bundle of high-dimensional data and the instances are labeled as outliers or not. I am looking to get some insights around *where these outliers reside within the data.* I seek to answer questions like:

1. Are the outliers spread far apart from each other? Or are they clustered together?
2. Are the outliers lying 'in-between' clusters of good data? Or are they on the 'edge' boundaries of the data?
3. If outliers are clustered together, how do these cluster densities compare with clusters of good data?
4. 'Where' are the outliers?

What kind of techniques will let me find these insights? If the data was 2 or 3-dimensional, I can easily plot the data and just *look* at it. But I can't do it high-dimensional data.

Comment: This may be a better fit on Cross Validated SE, the statistics site.

Comment: How many dimensions do you have? What kind of data is it?

Answer (score 0):

**Analyzing the Statistical Properties of Outliers**

- First of all, if you can choose to focus on specific features. For
  example, if you know a featues is subject to high  variation, you can
  draw a box plot. You can also draw a 2D graph if you want to focus on
  2 features. THis shows how much the labelled outliers vary.
- Next, there's a metric called a Z-score, which basically says how
  many standard devations a point varies compared to the mean. The
  Z-score is signed, meaning if a point is below the mean, the Z-score
  will be negative. This can be used to analyze all the features of the
  dataset. You can find the threshold value in your labelled dataset for which all the points above that threshold are labelled outliers
- Lastly, we can find the interquartile range and similarly filter
  based on it. The IQR is simply the difference between the 75
  percentile and 25 percentile. You can also use this similarly to Z-score.

Using these techniques, we can analyze some of the statistical properties of the outliers.
If you also want to analyze the clusters, you can adapt the [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) algorithm to your problem. This algorithm clusters data based on densities, so it will be easy to apply the techniques to outliers.